# How do I create regex groups for replacement?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

I have this sample string:

```
Image:  SGD$45.32 SKU: 3f3f3 dfdfd grg4t BP 6yhf Pack Size: 1000's Color: Green Price: SGD$45.32 SGD$45...
```

I would like to remove all the prices namely:

```
SGD$45.32  
Price: SGD$45.32  
SGD$45
```

I have this expression thats supposed to match the 3 groups:

```
$pattern = '/(Price.+\sSGD\$\d+\.\d{2})(SGD\$\d+\.\d{2})(SGD\$\d+)/';  
$new_snippet = preg_replace($pattern, '', $snippet);
```

But apparently its not working.

It works if I replace a single group at a time. But, I'd like to know if it possible to replace all possible matching groups with a single statement.

Tried `preg_match_all($pattern, $snippet, $matches);` to show matches based on the above pattern, but no matches are found if I put all 3 groups together.

Comment: is price always at the end of the string? meaning can we cut off everything after Price:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$output = preg_replace(array('/Price: /s', '/SGD\$.+? /s'), '', $input);
```

Comment: this will delete 'Price: ' and 'SGD$xxx ', xxx being anything before the next space.

Comment: @resting no problem. glad to help. by the way, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question: use `|` to conditionally group them:

```
$pattern = '/(Price.+\sSGD\$\d+\.\d{2})|(SGD\$\d+\.\d{2})|(SGD\$\d+)/';
```

This replaces a substring if it matches *any* of:

- `(Price.+\sSGD\$\d+\.\d{2})`
- `(SGD\$\d+\.\d{2})`
- `(SGD\$\d+)`

---

I would rewrite the entire regex into this though:

```
$pattern = '/(?:Price.+\s*)?SGD\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?/';
```

This would replace occurrences of `Price: SGD$45` as well.

Comment: perfect! i didn't know there's an | condition to apply to groupings. Any name for that? Would like to read up if there's any other conditions that we can apply :)

Comment: @resting: Not too sure, I just call it by its character name (the pipe). You can read up on other metacharacters in the PCRE syntax here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try separating them with |'s?